# HackerRank Project Euler #1

Tags: python

What is wrong with this code? It is not passing case 2 & 3 on HackerRank.

```
T=long(input())
while T>0:
    N=long(input())
    sum=0
    for i in range (1,N):
        if i%3==0 or i%5==0:
            sum+=i
    print (sum)
    T-=1
```

I'm new in programming and can't figure out what I did wrong.

https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler001

Comment: What is the expected behavior?  What errors does it raise as you run it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of issues with the code. First since you're using `long` I guess you're running it on Python 2. On Python 2 [`range`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) will generate a `list` and you'll run out of memory since problem description states that max `N` is `10^9`. You could fix that problem by switching to [`xrange`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) that returns [xrange object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-xrange) instead.

If you make the change described above the second issue would be speed. Since max `N` is `10^5` you'd potentially have to iterate over `10^14` numbers which takes far too long. In order to fix the used algorithm needs to be changed. You can use formula `n * (n + 1) * mul / 2` to calculate the sum of all multiples of `mul` in range `0...n`. Then you solve a case by just adding the sum of multiples of `3` and `5` and subtract multiples of `15`:

```
def sum_multiples(num, mul):
    n = num / mul
    return n * (n + 1) * mul / 2

for _ in xrange(int(raw_input())):
    num = int(raw_input()) - 1
    print sum_multiples(num, 3) + sum_multiples(num, 5) - sum_multiples(num, 15)
```

Answer (score 1):

The Answer is perfectly correct The Problem is Timeout.
to compute 10000 iteration the complexity should be minumal.
Your program's Complexity is O(n*n)

The Below Program has Complexity O(n)

```
t=int(input())
def ar(x):
    return x*(x+1);
for i in range(t):
    n =int(input())
    n -=1;
    a=int(n/3);
    b=int(n/5);
    c=int(n/15);
    print(int(int(3*ar(a) + 5*ar(b) - 15*ar(c))>>1));
```

For More Detail Explanation  you can view my blog [Learnlikepro.com](http://learnlikepro.com/project-euler/1-multiples-of-3-and-5/)